# DRF + SerializerMethodField with Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Unlike [this question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4g7ymwNjyAhU0hv0HHbAlDEIQFnoECB8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F37475829%2Fdjango-rest-framework-how-to-update-serializermethodfield&usg=AOvVaw0Wk2LaUmh4Smwey8NU6Ckz) I do not only want to read the data from my `SerializerMethodField` but also write in it:

Model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 34)
    note = models.CharField("additional info", max_length = 128, blank = True, null = True)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 34)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_artist")

    def get_artist(self, obj):
        return [obj.artist.pk, obj.artist.name, obj.artist.note]

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        lookup_field = "name"
        fields = ["name", "artist",]
        read_only_fields = ["name",]
```

ViewSet:

```
class AlbumViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
    lookup_field = "name"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, artist = None):
        query = Album.objects.filter(artist = artist)
        results = AlbumSerializer(data = query, many = True)
        results.is_valid()
        return Response(results.data)

    def put(self, request, name):
        print("------->", name, request)
        return Response("test")
```

Getting data from the API works just fine, but when calling `api/nevermind` I see all the album data but not the dropdown for artist in the browsable API view of DRF.

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter() 
router.register('albums', views.AlbumViewSet, basename = "albums")             

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.ListView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    url('^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Share `urls.py`

Comment: I added it to the first post.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it properly. You want being able to both read and write in `artist` field? If that so, you should separate these two as two serializer

Comment: I want a dropdown of all artists in the DRF HTML API where I can choose one to update. Right now the `GET` returns the artist correctly, but if I want to update it, I need a list of all artists to for example move an album from Nine Inch Nails -> Nirvana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SerializerMethodField for writing. Read the first sentence in [the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

You need to use a nested serializer here. Something like that:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ["id", "name", "note"]
        

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        lookup_field = "name"
        fields = ["name", "artist",]
        read_only_fields = ["name",]
```

Note that you will need to rewrite the save method of AlbumSerializer in order for writing on the nested serializer to work. [Check the doc for more info](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

> Getting data from the API works just fine, but when calling api/nevermind I see all the album data but not the dropdown for artist in the browsable API view of DRF.

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to see any kind of dropdowns for nested serializers or even for slug/pk-related fields. This will require Django to make an additional request to the server/DB to get the data.

Not sure if I can suggest good ways of having a dropdown like that, I have only ugly ones in mind.

Comment: ah ok ... I was sure it could be done easily. If I would for example just use your example I get two string inputs for "name" and "note" and not a dropdown - the extra DB query is an argument I did not consider before tbh. I kind of expected DRF to perfom this "under the hood".